# How to rename all folders starting with 'zz_' from 'zz_name' to 'name'?

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to write a batch to rename multiple folders. I have got the below script which I'm pretty sure will work if I target only the desired folders in the directory. I want to remove characters from a folder name so `zz_name` can be renamed to `name`.

The problem is my script is looking on the first 3 characters and rename all folders, not just those with `zz_`. I'm thinking at worst I could move the `zz_` folders to their own directory, rename them, and move them back. But that seems like a long way to go.

Is it possible to target only `zz_` in folder name?

```
setlocal
for /d %%i in (*) do call :rename %%i
goto :eof
:rename
set ZZDIR=%1
ren "%ZZDIR%" "%ZZDIR:~3%"
```

Comment: isn't that just `for /d %%i in (zz_*) do call: rename %%i` ? And doesn't this actually rename `zz_dirname` to `dirname`?

Comment: derrp.... i feel silly now. thanks. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Adam Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3058609/adam-smith) has answered already the question.

However, here is an improved batch code for this question.

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /d %%i in (zz_*) do call :RenDir %%i
endlocal
goto :EOF

:RenDir
set "ZZ_DIR=%1"
set "NEWDIR=%ZZ_DIR:~3%"
if not "%NEWDIR%"=="" if not exist "%NEWDIR%" ren "%ZZ_DIR%" "%NEWDIR%"
```

1. This batch file ignores a directory with just `zz_` as name.
2. And it also does not try to rename for example `zz_xxx` to `xxx` if there is already a directory `xxx`.